# Slickgrid header menu sorting is not working properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

In my case, Once I clear the column sorting and try to resort to the Ascending by the slick grid header menu. During this action, **the column values are shuffled, again and again**.
I don't know the reason why sorting is not working properly in the slick grid.

[image]

As per our expectation, Using the slick grid header menu sorting (ascending) and repeatedly clicking the sort ascending, the column value should not shuffle again and again. So kindly provide a proper solution for this sorting issue.

**Software versions:**

- Angular: 13.3.9
- Angular-Slickgrid: 4.3.1
- slickgrid-universal: 1.4.0
- TypeScript: 4.6.4
- Operating System: Windows 10
- Node: 14.18.3
- NPM: 6.14.8

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid

That was a bug, so you could have open a GitHub issue for that (I opened one for your [issue 1052](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/issues/1052)). I looked into this and it was challenging to fix, the lib uses MomentJS (moment-mini actually) and date sorting with Moment is not exactly straightforward when dealing with potential null values. Anyway long story short, I have a fix in this Slickgrid-Universal [PR](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/pull/831) (to be released in the next few days for Angular-Slickgrid 5.x only).

However please note that I only support latest version and I see you are on older version so you won't get the fix unless you upgrade to latest. It is simply too much work for a single person (me) to support more than 1 version at a time, since the lib is a free Open Source project and I don't get any money from this work (apart from the very rare ko-fi contributions).

What if you can't upgrade just yet? You can define your own `sortComparer` on each column, so you could add the fix manually but that means that you will have to add the `sortComparer` on every date field of your grid(s)... so even though it would be easier to upgrade, at least you now have a workaround in the meantime.

```js
this.columnDefinitions = [
{
  id: 'finish', name: 'Finish', field: 'finish', sortable: true,
  // ... other options
  sortComparer: (val1, val2, sortDirection) => {
    let diff = 0;
    if (val1 === val2) {
      diff = 0;
    } else {
      let date1: Moment | Date = moment(val1, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
      let date2: Moment | Date = moment(val2, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
      // when date is invalid, we'll create a temporary old date
      if (!date1.isValid()) {
        date1 = new Date(1001, 1, 1);
      }
      if (!date2.isValid()) {
        date2 = new Date(1001, 1, 1);
      }
      diff = date1.valueOf() - date2.valueOf();
    }

    return sortDirection * diff;
  },
}]
```

if you plan to reuse it multiple time then extract it to a separate function & file

```js
function sortDateWithFix(val1, val2, sortDirection) {
  let diff = 0;
  if (val1 === val2) {
    diff = 0;
  } else {
    let date1: Moment | Date = moment(val1, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
    let date2: Moment | Date = moment(val2, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true);
    // when date is invalid, we'll create a temporary old date
    if (!date1.isValid()) {
      date1 = new Date(1001, 1, 1);
    }
    if (!date2.isValid()) {
      date2 = new Date(1001, 1, 1);
    }
    diff = date1.valueOf() - date2.valueOf();
  }

  return sortDirection * diff;
}

this.columnDefinitions = [
{
  id: 'start', name: 'Start', field: 'start', sortable: true,
  sortComparer: sortDateWithFix,
},
{
  id: 'finish', name: 'Finish', field: 'finish', sortable: true,
  sortComparer: sortDateWithFix,
}]
```

Note that the new code is taking slightly more time to execute because we now create a temp date in the past to sort nullish values, however it seems negligeable 1240ms vs 1125ms on the first sort of 50k unsorted rows (so about 100-150ms longer than before).